# (int)4294967295.0 = 2147483647?

Tags: c

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%d", (int)4294967295.0);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints 2147483647 on the codepad (http://codepad.org/yDCqFdTT)
and -2147483648 on my vs2012 settings. Expected -1. Converting 4294967295.0 to unsigned integer correctly yields -1, however.

What's happening? How can I safely convert my double to int? This kind of error is way beyond the range of rounding error.

Comment: How would conversion to an *unsigned* value give a negative value as result?

Comment: Why do you expect `-1`?

Comment: "Expected -1." The expectation has no basis in reality. This is undefined behaviour. "correctly yields -1". For incorrect values of "correctly". Printing an unsigned int with "%d" is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : He has used `"%d"` for printing. OP should use `"%u"`.

Comment: I expected -1 because (int)4294967295 often overflows to -1.

Comment: Maybe I should use fmod to truncate numbers before converting it. I found this problem while handing arguments from lua. Some people prefers writing integer>=0x80000000, while some people prefers writing negative number to lua code. I had to deal with the both without losing benefits of using double as lua_Number.

Comment: `4294967295` has type `long long int`. Converting it to `int` causes implementation-defined behaviour. There is no requirement that this behaviour be related to the undefined behaviour in your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to draft N1256 (C99) §6.3.1.4, you are invoking undefined behavior:

> ### 6.3.1.4 Real floating and integer
>
> 1. When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than `_Bool`, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.<sup>50)</sup>
> 2. When a value of integer type is converted to a real floating type, if the value being converted can be represented exactly in the new type, it is unchanged. If the value being converted is in the range of values that can be represented but cannot be represented exactly, the result is either the nearest higher or nearest lower representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner. If the value being converted is outside the range of values that can be represented, the behavior is undefined.
>
> 50) The remaindering operation performed when a value of integer type is converted to unsigned type need not be performed when a value of real floating type is converted to unsigned type. Thus, the range of portable real floating values is (−1, `Utype_MAX+1`).

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is undefined behaviour: casting a value to a numerical type `int` which can't hold it.

Depending on your platform (if `int` is 32 bit) the integer part of this value is too big to be represented by an unsigned int. Anything can happen then, since the standard explicitly tells the compiler/hardware can do whatever it likes.

You could use something like `boost::numeric_cast` to test for this kind of problems.

Comment: 4294967295.0 is a double, and double can store 4294967295 exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The convertion from double to int first disregards the fractional part, giving 4294967295. This number is not representable in type int, therefore the result is undefined behaviour. The result could be any number. Your computer could crash or explode. Anything could happen because your code invokes undefined behaviour.